# cp or ls command. File exist, but I get no such file or directory message

Tags: files, find

I have an linux car player. I need to copy libmedia-navi.so file from device to sd-card. But I can not. `ls` command lists some files with only "file name" and some files with "file name -> another file name" for example "libmedia-navi.so -> libmedia-tts.so". I dont know why it is.

```
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    4 1000     root          4096 Jan  1  1970 gstreamer
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 Jan  1  1970 libmedia-navi.so -> libmedia-tts.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 Jan  1  1970 libmedia-prompt.so -> libmedia-wav.so
```

Also I can not copy libmedia-navi.so file to sd card or other location because it gives “No such file or directory” error.

```
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib# cp /svp/lib/libmedia-navi.so /media/sdcard0/
cp: can't stat '/svp/lib/libmedia-navi.so': No such file or directory
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib#
```

Also I can not understand, find command. Can find libmedia-navi.so file, but can not find libmedia-tts.so.

```
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib# find /. -name 'libmedia-navi.so'
/./svp/lib/libmedia-navi.so
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib#

root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib# find /. -name 'libmedia-tts.so'
root@dra7xx-g5-r1:/svp/lib#
```

How can I access and copy libmedia-navi.so file.

Comment: You are trying to copy a symbolic link, not a file. Copy `libmedia-tts.so` which is the file.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lL` for this directory? and Did you show the full listing in your question?

Comment: To add clarity to my previous comment, I don't know what distro you are using but there is usually an indication that link is broken. If `libmedia-navi.so` is pointing to `libmedia-tts.so` and `find` isn't returning anything then that means that the link is effectively broken and nothing will get copied.

Comment: `ls -lL` not list  libmedia-navi.so or libmedia-tts.so. @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: ls -lL output: `ls: ./libmedia-navi.so: No such file or directory` @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: @g770like, that is odd, ether you have not reported the output of `ls -lL`, correctly or your system is totally broken.

Comment: What **is** the output of `ls -lL` for this directory? Please **show** in **question**. (don't **describe** what is **not**.

Answer (score 2):

The files with the `->` are symbolic links, see also the `l` at the start of the mode.

When you copy them, by default it copies what they point to. If the file that they point to does not exist, then you will get an error.